# Rails 7 doesn’t generate SCSS file on the `generate scaffold` command

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, code-generation

I created a new fresh project in Rails 7, and whenever I use the generating script

`rails generate scaffold` or `rails generate controller`, all of the generated files are created except the css/scss.

Apparently, [I'm not the only one with the issue](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/rails-doesnt-generate-scaffolds-scss-or-any-controller-related-css-files/79751)

There's a claim on that link that in Rails 7, the CSS files are not generated by default.

**Is there a way to force rails CLI to generate styles on the scaffold command?**

**And in anyway, why did they make that change in Rails 7, if the claim is true?**

Here's the script I ran and the output in my given console:

```
rails g scaffold WhyNoCss dont_work:boolean
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20220215221757_create_why_no_csses.rb
  create    app/models/why_no_css.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/models/why_no_css_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/why_no_csses.yml
  invoke  resource_route
   route    resources :why_no_csses
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/why_no_csses_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  create      app/views/why_no_csses
  create      app/views/why_no_csses/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/why_no_csses/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/why_no_csses/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/why_no_csses/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/why_no_csses/_form.html.erb
  create      app/views/why_no_csses/_why_no_css.html.erb
  invoke    resource_route
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/controllers/why_no_csses_controller_test.rb
  create      test/system/why_no_csses_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/why_no_csses_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  invoke    jbuilder
  create      app/views/why_no_csses/index.json.jbuilder
  create      app/views/why_no_csses/show.json.jbuilder
  create      app/views/why_no_csses/_why_no_css.json.jbuilder
```

Comment: A half solution to this issue is directly generating the SCSS file by using the rails CLI command `rails g scss:assets [scaffold NAME]`. This would generate an empty style file in the `app/assets/stylesheets` directory.

You'll still have to manually link the style to the views to.

So ,again, why would I use this command when I can just create the stylesheet file in the code editor?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to force rails CLI to generate styles?

While you can add `--css sass` (also: `tailwind`, `postcss`, `bootstrap`) to `rails new` commands, the ability to generate CSS files with a `scaffold` command was removed in `v7.0.0.alpha1` ([PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43110), [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d5b9618da1ac60c674e8a27c3ab4e33742e9aa9b)).

> And in anyway, why did they make that change in Rails 7, if the claim is true?

You can read the justification on the PR in addition to [their blog post](https://rubyonrails.org/2021/12/15/Rails-7-fulfilling-a-vision) on Rails 7 that mentions CSS changes.

Comment: Tried `rails generate scaffold test title:string --css sass` And it didn't generate any style file.

I checked the command via `rails generate scaffold --help`, and again no `css` can be found in the output.

Comment: Looks like I was slightly off. This is available on `rails new` commands, not `rails generate`. An example can be found on [this blog post](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/11/17/rails-7-added-css-app-generator.html).

Comment: Again, tried every option and it still won't generate style files when using `scaffold` command.

The only thing it does is add famous CSS library, which is obvious from the assuming what the option does.

I honestly don't understand their reason for not generating any JS & CSS files anymore.

Every page needs it's own custom CSS and definitely needs some JS for making the page more responsive. 

Also, I read the blog post and not once did they mention the removal of generating CSS & JS files from `rails generate scaffold` command :/

Comment: To create new rails on a specific version, check this link I found just now:  https://www.aloucaslabs.com/miniposts/using-a-specific-rails-version-when-you-generate-a-new-rails-app-with-rails-new-command

Comment: About `Rails 6.1.4.6`, it actually did generate a StyleSheet file, but no JS file.

Comment: Just got mine working and that lines up with what I got as well. I think [this PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43110) is what removed it. [These lines](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43110/files#diff-210d0f245e618b7f8c6fcb53f518bd7fd343ce7e5d8c609ecfdb149418beca19L224-L226) show the guide being updated to remove the option to generate CSS with `scaffold`.

Comment: For reference, I went ahead and updated the answer above to include this information.