# Making $rails g scaffold make css style sheets like how it used to in previous versions (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffold

When using $rails g scaffold it doesn't make any css stylesheets like how it used to in older versions. Is there any way I can make the command run how it used to? Or modify it to still make those style sheets (without installing an older version of ruby)I'm following along this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyvWz5TUWg and am about 1hr and 6minutes in.

I'm currently using rails v7.0.3.1

Comment: Which version of rails you are using and did you setup as api only?

Comment: I'm using rails 7.0.3.1, I was following this tutorial  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyvWz5TUWg I got to around 1hr and 6mins into the tutorial. I followed his command but it doesnt create the css style sheet due to me having a more up to date version of ruby than him

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71136107/13815168